# iot gprs sends event to ggogle assistant and triggers a pushed intent to initiate a full dialog -> general guidance

Tags: iot, gprs

A gprs initiated event from an IOT device shall invoke a dialog on google assistant without the users having to start the dialog themselves. IOW. the begin of the dialog is externally triggered by an event and this event and not the user starts a dialog. Can this be done?

I am a NodeJs convert from one of the two other dialog management systems and know how to write a dialog and have limited know-how on google assistant to react to events.

There is an IOT device that sends GPRS messages to a google assistant device in case of a status change. This should trigger a push event on the assistant's host device which speaks a message about the event and allows the recipient to control further actions through a predefined dialog.

An 'alarm' on 'google home' fulfills the first requirement: Not the user but an external event (timer) triggers the dialog without there being a permanent connection during the timer countdown. 
This alarm, however, does not seem to be a dialog as it only allows to 'stop' it.

As far as I found does it seem hard -and was impossible some time ago- to barge into a device without prior activation by a user. I do not know if it is possible to emulate a user request action to initiate a dialog or if there are better ways to push an event to initiate an intent that starts -without having been activated by the user- a dialog. (Those dialogs are approved and expected by the user)